# How do I see what queries are running on an interbase database

Tags: interbase

I have a Interbase 7.x database being used by an application.

I want to know which queries are run by that application in different scenarios.

Does anyone know about how to "profile" an interbase database and see which queries are currently running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use InterBase Performance Monitor. It's built into IBConsole, or you can get [a standalone version](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/23629).

Alternately:

```
SELECT * FROM TMP$STATEMENTS;
```